# Is there a way to stop Hibernate from corrupting boolean literals in @Where annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, boolean, hsqldb

I'd like to use `@Where` annotation in Hibernate to remove objects which have been marked 'deleted' by a boolean property on that object. For example the following should prevent any deleted addresses from being loaded by Hibernate:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="contact")
@Where(clause="deleted=FALSE")
private Set<Address> addresses;
```

However when I use a clause like `deleted=FALSE` then Hibernate will mangle the boolean literal by prefixing it with a table name, which causes the query to fail. For example:

```
select ... from address address0_ where  ( address0_.deleted=address0_.FALSE)  and address0_.contact_id=?
```

What I expected is something like `(address0_.deleted=FALSE)` instead of `(address0_.deleted=address0_.FALSE)`.

Is there a way to specify the @Where clause or configure Hibernate to correctly output the boolean value?

---

*PS.* Note that it is possible with *some* databases to specify the boolean value as a string literal like this:

```
@Where(clause="deleted='FALSE'")
```

That will get converted to `(address0_.deleted='FALSE')` which works just fine in, for example, PostgreSQL. However I am using HSQLDB for this project, and HSQLDB does not seem to support boolean string literals. On HSQL I get the following exception when using `deleted='FALSE'`:

`org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid character value for cast`

Comment: Did you remember to specify HSQLDB Dialect in the hibernate setup?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` and I've double-checked that Hibernate is actually using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've discovered bug reports about this which have been unresolved for more than six years! The Hibernate issue tracker has [HHH-1587](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1587), [HHH-2775](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2775) and [ANN-647](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-647) on the problem.

The solution is to create a custom Dialect class which registers `true`, `false` and `unknown` as keywords (these are the official boolean literals in the SQL spec). This causes Hibernate to recognise them as keywords and thus stop prefixing them as if they were columns.

Here's my custom Dialect class which solved the problem for me:

```
public class ImprovedHSQLDialect extends HSQLDialect {

    public ImprovedHSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerKeyword("true");
        registerKeyword("false");
        registerKeyword("unknown");
    }
}
```

Once this dialect is in use, `@Where(clause="deleted=FALSE")` works correctly.

Comment: It looks like HHH-1587 and ANN-647 got fixed meanwhile. Well, another six years have passed since you posted this answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

When the column is created as BOOLEAN in the table defintion, the latest HSQLDB supports `WHERE active = TRUE` , `WHERE active = 'TRUE'` as well as `WHERE active`.

Hibernate may be creating a BIT column, in which case `WHERE active = TRUE`, `WHERE active = B'1'` or `WHERE active = 1` will work.

Please use version 2.2.8 or greater for these capabilities.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The error described in my question occurred on the latest HSQLDB (version 2.2.8). The current documentation doesn't mention any support for string-boolean conversion in http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html so I'm not convinced that's a feature of HSQLDB.

Comment: The docs cannot cover all possible conversions. If the table has a BOOLEAN column, then all the above work. Hibernate must be creating a BIT column, in which case WHERE active = TRUE, WHERE active = B'1' or WHERE active = 1 will work.

Comment: In that case it's possible that specifying the appropriate `columnDefinition` in the `@Column` annotation might make it work. But as far as I am concerned it's wrong for Hibernate to treat a reserved word like `FALSE` as a column name, so I think it's a better solution to use the `registerKeyword` method as I describe in my answer — it's simple and instantly fixes it in all Hibernate objects.